# If StringBuilder is mutable, then why do StringBuilder methods return a StringBuilder object?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

We all know that `strings` are immutable and StringBuilder is `mutable`. Right. Then why does its methods returns a `StringBuilder` object. Should they all not be void methods?

Why this

```
public StringBuilder Append(bool value)
```

and not

```
public void Append(bool value)
```

Any example explaining use of this would be great.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's called a ["fluent interface"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).  It allows you to chain together calls by repeated dot notations.

```
return new StringBuilder()
  .Append("Hello, ")
  .Append("world!")
  .ToString();
```

Comment: Use dotPeek to view the StringBuilder class you will see over 1500 lines of code which will without any doubt show what it does and how it does it.

Comment: There is an example under the C# part of the wiki page!

Comment: OK, but the code snippet was added in by Dennis when the comment was made.  Why is mine singled out and not the other answer below?

Comment: @Monkieboy : how does reading 1500 lines of source code clarify the design intentions, when you already could not infer it from the function signatures?

Comment: My gripe is not with the edit.  I agree that it's better.  I don't always have time to devote to every answer, so I contribute what I can.  If somebody comes along later and improves it I have no problem.  It's the commentary from people who have contributed nothing beyond their self-appointed moderator comments that bugs me.

Comment: @omer - I was actually responding to the request for an example and what is a better example than the code itself, which in this case it too long to paste here, which is why I suggested looking at the decompiled sources. Also, should a method reveal design intent as well as functional intent... I personally think that in many cases it would be a tall order.

Answer (score 15):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Most of the methods that modify an instance of this class return a
>   reference to that same instance. Since a reference to the instance is
>   returned, you can call a method or property on the reference. This can
>   be convenient if you want to write a single statement that **chains
>   successive operations one after another**.

**Example**:

```
string user = new StringBuilder()
    .AppendFormat("Name: {0}", user.Name)
    .AppendLine()
    .AppendFormat("Email: {0}", user.Email)
    .AppendLine()
    .ToString();
```

This is typically called [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).